# Railsで複数のhas_manyを持ったモデルを作りたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

多くのlibrary（製品）があり、それぞれのlibraryには多くのdoc（書類が）あります。またそれぞれの製品に多くのpict(画像）がある。
二つに分けたいのは書類は種類や備考がありますが、pictはサムネールの表示をしたいからです。

library.rb

```
has_many :docs
has_many :picts
```

doc.rb

```
belongs_to :library
```

pict.rb

```
belongs_to :library
```

としてあります。ここでlibraryコントローラーで

```
def show
  @docs = @library.docs.where(params[:library_id])
end

def pictshow　#ルーティングの設定はしてある
  @picts = @library.picts.where(params[:library_id])
end
```

になっておりますが、showではエラーが出ないのですが、pictshowで

```
NoMethodError in LibrariesController#pictshow
undefined method `picts' for nil:NilClass
```

になってしまいます。原因が解りません

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> NoMethodError in LibrariesController#pictshow
> undefined method `picts' for nil:NilClass
> ```

`@library`が`nil`なので`@library.picts`が`NoMethodErrorになっています。

scaffoldで生成したコントローラであればコードはこうなっていると思います。

```
class LibrariesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_library, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_library
      @library = Library.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

`set_library`メソッドによって`@library`に然るべきidのLibraryがロードされるのですが、`set_library`が呼び出されるのは

```
  before_action :set_library, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

と、ここで指定されたメソッド(アクション)のみです。自分で追加したメソッドであれば、`before_action`にもそれを追加しないと`@library`は設定されないまま(参照したら`nil`)になります。

ついでに指摘しておきます

```
@docs = @library.docs.where(params[:library_id])
```

というコードですが、`@library.docs`は

```
@docs = Doc.where(library_id: @library.id)
```

と同じです。多分やりたいことは

```
 @docs = @library.docs
```

で十分なんじゃないでしょうか。

さらに言うと、`where(params[:library_id])`は多分`where(10)`とかになるので、意図しないクエリになっていると思います。

(暗黙の型変換でSQLとしては`SELECT ... WHERE TRUE`になってるかな？)

Comment: 大変わかりやすい説明を頂きありがとうございます。
無事画像が表示されました。
また、@dcosの指定も大変参考になりました。

Comment: @fuji 解決したのであればお礼コメントは不要なのでその代わりに回答の横にあるチェックマークを押して回答を「承認」してください。いつまでも未回答のまま残ってしまいますので。

Answer (score 1):

`@picts = @library.picts` の時点で値が`nil`になっています。該当の`@library`が一枚も`pict`を持っていないためです。

Comment: ご回答、有難うございます。defaultのアクション以外の時は@libraryのidの指定をしないと、いけないのが解りませんでした。

Answer (score 0):

```
@library = nil 
@library.picts 
#-> undefined method `picts' for nil:NilClass
```

になります。
もし、nilの場合にエラーを出したくないならば、

```
 @library = nil 
 @library.try(:picts)
 #-> nil(エラーは出ない)
```

を使うことで避ける事ができます。